# Установка плагина IvyIdea

Tags: intellij-idea, сборка

Подскажите как установить плагин IvyIdea, что бы собрать проект?

P.S.погуглила, не нашла понятного мануала

Comment: А что конкретно вам непонятно в [официальной документации по установке плагинов в IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html) и [официальной документация плагина IvyIDEA](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/IvyIDEA)?

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

1. [официальная документация по установке плагинов в IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html)
2. [официальная документация плагина IvyIDEA](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/IvyIDEA)